# Proxy/Firewall Issues

Tags: python, configuration, proxy, firewall

I'm fairly new and limited in my `Python` knowledge. I recently made the change to begin working telecommute for work (which is dreamy). To connect to our shared servers (which is where my `Python` files live), I must connect `VPN`.

I had no problems running the modules when I was at my work's headquarters locations but since working telecommute and being on the `VPN`, I'm running into this error:

```
IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection.
Either IDLE can't start a subprocess or
personal firewall software is blocking the connection.
```

Our work's IT department is ridiculous and excessive on security (I spend a good chunk of my day arguing with them that I'm not violating company policy but rather doing my job). I spoke to one friend I have in the IT department and he confirmed my suspicion that we use different *ports* and *proxies* on the `VPN` than we do within the headquarters.

He will provide me with the updated port and proxy numbers so I may edit this within my `Python` settings. Unfortunately, I am so uneducated regarding `Python`, I just can't seem to figure out where these areas are.

Any help?

Comment: *"running into this error"* - when trying to do what exactly?

Comment: Sorry, when I hit "Run Module." I can open the files in Idle, use the # to update which groups and modules I want to run, save it (just like I was able to do from the HQ locations) but then when I hit "Run Module", I'm getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Most Python developers don't use IDLE - so please don't assume we know what "Run Module" does / is supposed to do. It sounds like some sort of remote code execution, but you'd need to provide details on that.

Comment: As I said, my knowledge is extremely limited. I wouldn't have known that most developers don't use IDLE. I didn't write the query, I didn't chose or select the software; I just inherited this mess from a shitty coworker who left work without any notice. I'll try to figure something else out.